# PHP inside HTML makes SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token error?

Tags: php, html, onclick, syntax-error, unexpected-token

Im geting the error in the title it marks only ">" in the end of line 2 i have tried to change it to /> or simple thing like that but it seems not working at all...
the idea is to make a button that will send onclick this function using the ownerId That i gave using PHP.
if it does matter [ownerId] => ec8d1073-544e-4330-bc9c-6fcfc3fe9bab
thanks for reading and thanks again if you sent any help

```
<button onclick="SendCommMessageToOwner(<? echo $comm_data->info->ownerId; ?>)"
                    type="submit" class="elementor-button elementor-size-sm button-color-comm"> // right here
                    
                        <span>
                            <span class=" elementor-button-icon">
                            </span>
                        <span class="elementor-button-text">שליחה</span>
                        </span>
                    </button>
```

Comment: Did you try to put the php code inside single quotes? like '<? ... ?>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a *JavaScript* syntax error, not a *PHP* syntax error.  So what is the JavaScript code in the browser that causes the error?  You're not showing it, but you provide a clue:

> if it does matter [ownerId] => ec8d1073-544e-4330-bc9c-6fcfc3fe9bab

So the JavaScript code will be:

```
SendCommMessageToOwner(ec8d1073-544e-4330-bc9c-6fcfc3fe9bab)
```

Yup, that's a syntax error alright.  I suspect you meant for that to be a string literal:

```
SendCommMessageToOwner('ec8d1073-544e-4330-bc9c-6fcfc3fe9bab')
```

Which means you're just missing the quotes in your markup (outside of the server-side code in this case):

```
<button onclick="SendCommMessageToOwner('<? echo $comm_data->info->ownerId; ?>')" ...
```